# MySQLSyntaxErrorException - Invalid Parameters in Prepared Statement

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I Have a code Like Below. I have Tried the Other Solutions in stack but nothing seems to be Working. The Java code which generates the Error is as Shown Below.

```
public Connection getConnection() 
    {
      try 
      {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNSTR, USER, PASS);
        return conn;
      }
      catch (SQLException e) 
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
      }
    }

    public boolean AuthenticateUser() 
    {   
        String UserName = "User";
        String Password = "Password";

        try 
        {
            PreparedStatement  pstmt = null;
            ResultSet          rs   = null;
            conn = getConnection();

            String strSQL = "SELECT UserName " +
                      "  FROM Users " +
                      " WHERE UserId   = ?  AND " + 
                      "       Password = ?";

          pstmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(strSQL);
          pstmt.setString(1, UserName);
          pstmt.setString(2, Password);

          System.out.println(strSQL);

          rs = pstmt.executeQuery(strSQL);

          System.out.println(rs.getRow());

          rs.last();
          int TotalRows = rs.getRow();
          System.out.println(TotalRows);

          if(TotalRows > 0)
            return true;
          else
            return false;  

        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
          return false;
        }         
    }
```

The Table Structure of the Database is as Given Below

```
CREATE TABLE Users(Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                   UserName VARCHAR(255),
                   UserId VARCHAR(255),
               Password VARCHAR(255))
```

The error is As given Below in [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJUje.jpg)
[image]

The Exception are as Below

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?  AND          Password = ?' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2618)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1557)
    at com.apryll.db.util.dbUtil.AuthenticateUser(dbUtil.java:55)
    at com.apryll.db.Login.doPost(Login.java:42)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What exceptions are you getting? Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Don't add snapshot. Copy and post the exception here. I can't even see that image.

Comment: Could u right click and choose view image

Comment: Why are you passing the SQL again as an argument to the `executeQuery` method? Can't find that signature in the API...

Comment: Thank you So  Much  Adrián López . Gr8

Comment: Did that fix your error? o.O I would expect a compiler error, not an stacktrace.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you Sooo Much Adrián López

Comment: @Adrián López write the answer so everyone will be able to learn and you'll get some points :)

Comment: @baraky ok... just did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the SQL again to the `executeQuery` method. That signature doesn't appear in the API. The method needs no arguments.

[executeQuery() javaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29)

Comment: It does appear in the API of `Statement` (superclass of `PreparedStatement`), but drivers should throw an exception when the `Statement` methods accepting a query-string are called from a `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the variable UserName as the first query parameter, but in the query you are using UserId which is an int and not a String.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for Reply. No I checked It Its String The Primary Field is Kept as Id

Comment: Kindly Check The Table Structure